# Which is the correct way of accessing a this element of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

On the **setClickEvents** funtion in the below javascript object when I try to use the **this** element inside the **addEventListener** it doesn't work, I have to use **tabUI**, the object itself.

I'm not sure if it's a good practice what I'm doing but it works.

What can I do for improving it?

```
var tabUI = {
    leftTab: undefined,
    rightTab: undefined,

    setTabs: function(leftTabId, rightTabId) {
        this.leftTab = document.getElementById(leftTabId);
        this.rightTab = document.getElementById(rightTabId);
    },

    setClickEvents: function() {
        this.leftTab.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // This works
            tabUI.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
            tabUI.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');

            // This doesn't work
            this.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
            this.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');
        });

        this.rightTab.addEventListener('click', function() {
            tabUI.leftTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');
            tabUI.rightTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) inside the event handler is the element on which the event has occurred.

You can solve your problem using any of the following two ways. I'd recommend you to use the second way, so that you can access the elements on which event has occurred.

1. [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) context

   **Changing the context of the function regardless of how it'll be called.**

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
this.leftTab.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // This works
  tabUI.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
  tabUI.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');

  // This also works here
  this.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
  this.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');
}.bind(this));
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

2. Cache context/`this`

   **Cache the previous *context* and then, that can be used in the event handler.**

```js
var that = this; // Cache this here
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

this.leftTab.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // This works
  tabUI.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
  tabUI.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');

  // That works here
  that.leftTab.classList.add('tab_selected');
  // ^^^
  that.rightTab.classList.remove('tab_selected');
  // ^^^
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second example and it works. But the first one looks more elegant, can you show me a better example of why is better?

Comment: @user3561335 See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p4xanz8u/2/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p4xanz8u/3/) for illustration. See the comments in the second link

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object isn't `tabUI`, as you seem to have noticed. What it is is the element the event is running on: event handlers have their context set to the element they run on.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler